# Como fazer substring SelectListItem?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Segue o código:

**View:**

```
@model IEnumerable<Projeto.Models.Model>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th width="15%">Ações</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<nav>
    <ul class="pager">
        <li><a href="#" onclick="pagina(-1)">Anterior</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="pagina(1)">Próximo</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

**Controller:**

```
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var resultado= (from p in db.Tabela
                          where p.Campo== 1
                          select p).ToList();
            return View(resultado);
        }
```

Tentei fazer dessa forma:

```
        using (var db = new Entities())
        {
            var resultado = (from p in db.Tabela
                          where p.Campo == 1
                          select new SelectListItem
                          {
                              Value = p.descricao.Substring(0, 30)
                          }).ToList();
            return View(resultado );
        }
```

Recebo erro:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Projeto.Models.Model]'.

**Imagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode ver a imagem, o Id 60 e a descrição ficou muito grande, fez até barra de rolagem horizontal. Por isso quero fazer substring.

No primeiro código funciona, só que a descrição ficou muito grande. Quero fazer substring antes de fazer `return View()`

Comment: Esse ponto entes do operador de igualdade está no seu código mesmo? `p.Campo.== 1`, se tirar, resolve? Porque no segundo, usou um `Value`? E porque o objeto precisa ser um `SelectListItem` se no primeiro não precisa?

Comment: O que acontece é que sua View espera um `IEnumerable` diferente do que você está retornando na sua action, poste o código de sua view para melhor ajudarmos.

Comment: Talvez eu não preciso de SelectListItem, fazer um loop de cada descrição e substring(0, 15)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma rápida solução para o seu caso poderia ser o seguinte

```
var resultado = (from p in db.Tabela
                          where p.Campo == 1
                          select new Projeto.Models.Model
                          {
                              Id = p.Id,
                              Description = p.descricao.Substring(0, 30)
                          }).ToList();
            return View(resultado );
```

Comment: Não sabia que pode fazer `select new Projeto.Models.Model`

Comment: Valeu, ajudou aqui.